# beautifulsoup parse html tag exception

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, html-parsing

I'm extracting some information from html files. But some of the files do not have the tag `<p class="p p1"> date </p>`, which returns

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

And the date in some of the file is not inside the tag. I found one is:

```
<time content="2005-11-11T19:09:08Z" itemprop="datePublished">
 Nov. 11, 2005  2:09 PM ET
</time>
```

How do I solve these two problems?

My code:

```
month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October','November', 'December', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Aug', 'Oct', 'Dec']


def first_date_p():

    for p in soup.find_all('p', {"class": "p p1"}):
        for month in month_list:
            if month in p.get_text():
                first_date_p = p.get_text()
                date_start = first_date_p.index(month)
                date_text = first_date_p[date_start:]
                return date_text
            else:
            #if the tag exist, but do not have date.
                month = 'No Date/Error'
                return month.strip()
```

Comment: It appears to me that you should begin by looking for the characteristics of the dates that you want that apply to *all* the HTML files. Actually, there might be more that one format for the dates, and you'd need to handle each separately. How many different formats do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the selected 'p' tags always contain some text you can set the `text` argument to `True` , ie :

```
soup.find_all('p', {"class": "p p1"}, text=True)
```

Else, if you want to get all 'p' even if they don't contain any text you can turn `None` to string, eg :

```
str(p.get_text()).strip()
```

As for your second question, you can select the 'content' attribute of the 'time' tag, eg :

```
soup.find('time').get('content')
```